# Adding fields to contribution searches

Tags: contributions, search-results, civicampaign

I know that it is possible to [create profiles for Contacts that show up as options under "Search Views"](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/86/change-the-default-fields-columns-in-contact-search-results) in the Advanced Search screen:

I was hoping to add "Campaign" to the search results screen when searching for donations, but when I try to create a custom profile for this and begin to add a Contribution field, it says "Error: Contribution can not be used as a Result Column for profile searches."

[image: Error]

Is there another way to adjust which columns show up for Contribution searches?

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can create a group first using Advance search and in the contribution report try to list all the contact based on the group

This will provide you all the contribution column and also contact related columns

I guess this helps !!!