# How can I save Search results with preserving Views For Display Contacts (defined in Profile)?

Tags: profile, search-results, custom-search

I have a smart group which I would like to display with specific info in custom columns.

I can do **Advanced search**, select this group and choose predefined **Profile** in **Views For Display Contacts**. Then I get the group displayed with relevant custom columns.

How can I retrieve this view via link (to put it in Navigation menu)?

Comment: Are you asking how to add an item in civi navigation - ie via civicrm/admin/menu?reset=1, or something else?

Comment: as in how can you 'save' the 'show the results using this profile'.

Comment: if the latter, then afaik it can't currently be done, and i feel we have had same question in last month or so. maybe you could make an(other) effort to find it to see if it had an answer other than 'can't be done' ;-)

Comment: That's right. How can I search and show results using this profile with a single click?

Comment: What CMS are you using, since Drupal gives you many more options using Views

Comment: @petednz-fuzion How can I use these *Views*?

Comment: Are you asking me how to use Drupal Views?

Answer (score 1):

A partial solution is listed here: [Change the default fields (columns) in contact search results](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/86/change-the-default-fields-columns-in-contact-search-results)

> You can set this custom search profile with the reduced columns as a default for all contact search results (besides participants) in /civicrm/admin/setting/search?reset=1.

A major drawback is that I'd like to use **different columns for different searches** rather than the **default profile for *all* searches**.

Answer (score 1):

When you create (save) your smart group, following an advanced search, you also have a saved search in parallel, with an ssid (while the smart group has a gid) : look at the URL (that you can save and re-use).

I found no place in the User Interface where you can then retreive this ssid, but it is stored in the civicrm_saved_search table, that you can easily display with phpmyadmin.

Comment: Can you add it to the Navigation Menu via civicrm/admin/menu?reset=1

Comment: Jacques-Marie, I tried to identify what could I possibly use from that civicrm_saved_search table to create a search link, but failed to understand.

I'd be grateful, if you could provide some examples, how to locate the saved search in that table and to build an URL with that data.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize : I think I was a bit optimistic : this is the point where I am :

Create your search (you can use a Profile, whih customizes the results display columns).
Then, select all, create a smart group, and save it.

Look at the URL : it is in the form of :
yoursite.com/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?force=1&reset=1&**ssID=12**&context=advanced&qfKey= ....

Depending upon your permissions (I did not check that), you can use either of :

- yoursite.com/civicrm/contact/search/advanced?force=1&reset=1&**ssID=12**
  or
- yoursite.com/civicrm/group/search?force=1&context=smog&**gid=32**

(where gid is your smart group id) but, actually, they give the same result (while I thought that ssid would save the display profile).

I will come back here if I (or anybody else) find(s) a solution (because I am interested in).